# The last command from the docker file fails when building the image

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, frontend

I am trying to deploy an Angular docker application to heroku and i get an error on the last step of the docker file

Here is the error

```
Step 13/13 : COPY --from=builder /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat app/build/: file does not exist
```

And below is the docker file and the docker compose file

```
FROM node:14 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN curl -L https://github.com/a8m/envsubst/releases/download/v1.2.0/envsubst-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o envsubst && \
    chmod +x envsubst && \
    mv envsubst /usr/local/bin


COPY --from=builder /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.template
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
COPY --from=builder /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

```
version: '3'

services:

  angular:
    image: image_frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Also the nginx conf file

```
server {

    listen  ${PORT:=80};
    server_name  _;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $$uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: check to see if the build folder is created?

Comment: its not created

Comment: you tried to COPY something doesn't exist. Is that not the obvious error?

Comment: ok but why isnt it created ,  i am new to this

Comment: Look into the log, check to see when you run all those commands `RUN npm run build` was it successful and if so does the build folder get created inside /app/. Obviously, create the path would get you going but then there would be no contents you needed, right?